# Best practice to INSERT in MySQL Remote Database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, query-optimization

I'm trying to find the best way, or "practice" to do some INSERT queries.
My software is being developed on Visual Basic .NET, accessing to a MySQL Remote database.
I need to go through a loop, every day, and INSERT at least 50.000 records.
What would be the most optimized way to code this?.

For now, I'm opening a connection on each record and then sending the INSERT query. I know this is the worst way to do it, that's way i'm working to improve it.

I thought about splitting the whole loop into small groups and make queries with 1000 records each one. They're not too large, but they're a lot.

I've read something about mysql_ping, to keep the connection alive and avoid connecting, closing, conecting, and so on. So this way I could go through the loop with only 1 connection made at the start.

I'm a bit lost, which are your recommendations?

Thank you guys.

EDIT:
This is the code I'm using to make the queries:

```
    Public Function MYSQL_QUERY(ByVal QUERY As String) As Long
    Dim connStr As String = "Database=" & DB_NAME & ";" & _
                            "Data Source=" & DB_HOST & ";" & _
                            "User Id=" & DB_USER & ";Password=" & DB_PASSWORD


    Try
        Dim rowsEffected As Integer = 0
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(QUERY, connection)

        connection.Open()

        rowsEffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connection.Close()

        Return cmd.LastInsertedId
        Exit Function
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function
```

And I'm calling this function on each INSERT of the LOOP.

Comment: can you post a code example? otherwise it is difficult to advise you.

Comment: You could use threading within your program.

Comment: Why do you want to close the connection? Are you trying to avoid starving other programs? Within a single open connection, you should be able to batch N (say 1000) records at a time to insert.